# Проблема при чтении .csv-файла в pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Такой main.py

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

import pandas


def get_data_from_zip_file(zip_file_path, csv_filename):
    """Функция распаковывает .zip и читает данные и .csv-файла.

    Arguments:
        zip_file_path (str): путь от main.py до .zip-архива
        csv_filename (str): путь от main.py до .csv-файла

    Returns:
        csv_data (class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'):
         данные прочитанные из .csv-файла
    """
    with ZipFile(zip_file_path) as zip_file:
        with zip_file.open(csv_filename) as csv_file:
            csv_data = pandas.read_csv(
                csv_file,
                sep=',',
                decimal='.',
            )
    return csv_data

test_data = get_data_from_zip_file(
        zip_file_path='../test_Dipoles/Source_SF/SF_DA_20200419.csv.zip',
        csv_filename='SF_DA_202004190700.csv',
    )[:5]

print(test_data)

test_data.to_csv(
    '../output_data/test_data.csv',
    sep=',',
    index=False,
    encoding='utf-8',
)
```

Я смотрел .csv-файл и часть такая:

```
Constraint Class,GMT Interval,Constraint Name,Constraint Direction,Constraint Type,Constraint Cause,Curve ID,Segment ID,Node Name,Shift Factor
NOMOGRAM,04/21/2020 02:00:00 AM,7820_TL 230S_OVERLOAD_NG,LE,,Base Case,3,1,ENCINA4_7_B1,-0.10650000,
NOMOGRAM,04/21/2020 03:00:00 AM,7820_TL 230S_OVERLOAD_NG,LE,,Base Case,3,1,ENCINA4_7_B1,-0.10675000,
```

При этом вывод в консоль такой:

```
                Constraint Class  ... Shift Factor
NOMOGRAM  04/19/2020 06:00:00 PM  ...          NaN
NOMOGRAM  04/19/2020 07:00:00 PM  ...          NaN
```

А если выводить в файл то такой:

```
Constraint Class,GMT Interval,Constraint Name,Constraint Direction,Constraint Type,Constraint Cause,Curve ID,Segment ID,Node Name,Shift Factor
04/19/2020 06:00:00 PM,7820_TL 230S_OVERLOAD_NG,LE,,Base Case,3.0,1.0,ENCINA4_7_B1,-0.108,
04/19/2020 07:00:00 PM,7820_TL 230S_OVERLOAD_NG,LE,,Base Case,3.0,1.0,ENCINA4_7_B1,-0.10825,
```

Почему при выводе в консоль float заменяется на NaN?
Почему при выводе в файл не отображается Nomograd?
Как убрать округление Shift Factor?

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось проще, в конце изначального файла была лишняя запятая в конце каждой строчки. Нужно при чтении csv-файла добавить usecols=range(10) - это подскажет pandas сколько столбцов считать.
Нужно написать так:

```py
def get_data_from_zip_file(zip_file_path, csv_filename):
    """Функция распаковывает .zip и читает данные и .csv-файла.

    Arguments:
        zip_file_path (str): путь от main.py до .zip-архива
        csv_filename (str): название .csv-файла

    Returns:
        csv_data (class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'):
         данные прочитанные из .csv-файла
    """
    with ZipFile(zip_file_path) as zip_file:
        with zip_file.open(csv_filename) as csv_file:
            csv_data = pandas.read_csv(
                csv_file,
                sep=',',
                decimal='.',
                header=0,
                parse_dates=True,
                usecols=range(10),
            )
    return csv_data
```

Тогда и NaN пропадет и Nomograd отображается, правда округление все еще есть.